# nightwatchjs selector is not selecting an attribute with space

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js, end-to-end

I have a few pages on which I am running `nightwatchjs` to execute an end to end test.

```
<div role="tab" aria-selected="true" title="My TV"><span>MyReal TV</span></div>
```

I have a few tabs that I try to verify using code similar to below:

```
.verify.elementPresent('div[role="tab"][title="Portfolio"]', 1000)
```

The above works fine for the Portfolio tab. However, I have two tabs that fail and is returning not found. **My Tv** and **Daily Report** . Below fails for My Tv:

```
.verify.elementPresent('div[role="tab"][title="My Tv"]', 1000)
```

The Daily Report fails as well. I am wondering if it has something to do with the space in my title? Is there anything else I am doing wrong?

Comment: try `div[role="tab"] span[text()="My Tv"]` instead of `div[role="tab"][title="My Tv"]`

Comment: @Andersson thanks for the prompt reply. It doesn't work . Still returning not found.

Comment: I dont think space was the reason, can you upload the the html block of that tab so i can see some for attribute ? ps: you just want to verify the tab and elements within , or do something more?

Comment: @NuruSalihu, Can you check whether your `div` located inside `iframe`/`frame` element or not?

Comment: Gus please i apologised for westing your time. It turns out the url returned was wrong. The url comes in a json object and considering its not new , didn't bother to check. Have spent hours on this just to learn this now . Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the url was wrong in my case. It was frustrating, spent hours to learn this.

Something like below was returned for the url

```
http://stackoverflow.com//questions
```

Instead of

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions
```